# Tkinter: Dynamically Creating Button Grid Using Nested Loops

Tags: python, user-interface, button, tkinter, widget

Hello I am having trouble creating a grid of buttons using nested loops and finding there identity to assign each button a unique sound or noise. So far we have gone through trial and error to find that we cannot give each individual button a unique variable or access them. Here is the code so far:

```
from Tkinter import *

import random


root = Tk()
root.geometry("1000x600")

list=['kick','snare','pit bull','hi-hat']
colors=['blue', 'red', 'pink','royal blue','green','orange','cyan','purple','magenta','hot pink', 'gold','yellow','aqua','chartreuse', 'slate blue', 'blue violet', 'steel blue', 'dodger blue', 'lime', 'teal', 'plum', 'orchid','crimson', 'dark orange']
b=[]


frame=Frame(root)
Grid.rowconfigure(root, 0, weight=1)
Grid.columnconfigure(root, 0, weight=1)
frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N+S+E+W)
grid=Frame(frame)
grid.grid(sticky=N+S+E+W, column=0, row=7, columnspan=2)
Grid.rowconfigure(frame, 0, weight=1)
Grid.columnconfigure(frame, 0, weight=1)



for x in range(10):

for y in range(4):

    btn = (Button(frame,text=list[y] + " " +str(x+1), bg="white", activebackground=random.choice(colors)))
    btn.bind("<Enter>", lambda event, b=btn: b.configure(bg=random.choice(colors)))
    btn.bind("<Leave>", lambda event, b=btn: b.configure(bg="white"))
    btn.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event, b=btn: b.configure(bg=random.choice(colors)))
    btn.bind("<Button-3>", lambda event, b=btn: b.configure(bg=random.choice(colors)))
    btn.grid(column=x, row=y, sticky=N+S+E+W)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: If you want to create a list of widgets, create a _list_ of widgets (eg: `buttons.appen(Button(...)`. That lets you access each button. There's nothing that says you have to use unique variables for every widget.